# How to get focus owner?

Tags: java, gwt

Like KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getPermanentFocusOwner() in AWT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [HasFocusHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasFocusHandlers.html) interface. You can add [FocusHandlers](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/FocusHandler.html) to any widget that implements this interface. Then, whenever the focus changes on that particular widget, you'll get a FocusEvent.

Comment: Then we should be able to listen to adding new Widgets. Any new widget can be focusable. But we don't have something like java.awt.event.ContainerListener.
In GWT exists com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.InsertPanel interface but implementations don't have for example Add/RemoveWidgetHandler

Comment: I need to get the Focus Owner without information about created widgets